# Aria engine (MariaDB) can't search data by WHERE query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Storage engine in my MariaDB (like MySQL) database was changed from MyISAM engine to Aria engine by server administrator. After that, in some tables (primary int, varchar name, varchar producer) I can not search data by query `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`, although the data in the table are available.
I tryed query `OPTIMIZE TABLE` but result was the same.
After query `ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY ...` everything works as it should. And after some time breaks down again.
What could it be?

Comment: Could you show an example of a statement you try (even a simple one), and the error message you get?

Comment: Example: `SELECT * FROM class_2_1_1_5 WHERE code = 50436`, but no errors - just empty response. If I do query `SELECT * FROM class_2_1_1_5` line with `code=50436` is present